# How to set 'dependent: :destroy' an a Post with questions ans replies? (PG::ForeignKeyViolation)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When I try to **destroy** a *Post* I get this error:

```
PG::ForeignKeyViolation at /posts/92
ERROR:  update or delete on table "possible_answers" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_e2809cb61e" on table "answers"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) is still referenced from table "answers".
```

posts_controlller.rb

```
  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    if @post.destroy
      flash[:success] = "Post gelöscht."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Fehler."
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
    end
  end
```

- A **post** has **questions** and **replies**

  - A **question** has **possible_answers** and **answers**
  - A **reply** has **answers**

post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :replies, dependent: :destroy
end
```

question.rb

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post

  has_many :possible_answers, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :possible_answers, reject_if: proc {
    |attributes| attributes['title'].blank?
  }
end
```

possible_answer.rb

```
class PossibleAnswer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

answer.rb

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :reply
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :possible_answer
end
```

reply.rb

```
class Reply < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added "**on_delete: :cascade**" to the *questions, replies, possible_answers and answers* table. Now I can normally delete such a Post.

i.e.:

```
class CreatePossibleAnswers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :possible_answers do |t|
      t.references :question, index: true, foreign_key: {on_delete: :cascade}
      t.string :title

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```